# What is **mov eax, ds:(__dso_handle_ptr - 804DFF4h)[ebx]**?

Tags: assembly, nasm, masm, disassembly

I use IDA pro to disassembly ELF 32 bit file.

In the asm code it creates, I find one sentence as below:

```
mov     eax, ds:(__dso_handle_ptr - 804DFF4h)[ebx]
```

I have never seen asm code like this, and use nasm/masm to directly assembly it would generate errors...

After searching the code, I found this:

```
    __dso_handle    dd 0
```

But I don't found **__dso_handle_ptr** which is very strange...

Could anyone give me some help..? Thank you!

Comment: I believe the ds:(_sym - hexaddr)  is specifying the data segment.  So the 32-bit value at offset EBX in that data segment will be moved into the accumulator EAX.   Is __dso_handle_ptr referenced anywhere else in the disassembly?  My guess it that it's a symbol loaded from the elf binary.  The __dso_ prefix represents this symbol is from a Dynamic Shared Object.   handle_ptr is a pretty generic name.  You can Google "dso handle_ptr" for some clues.

Comment: This looks like a reference to a dynamically-placed symbol from a shared object - it allows shared objects to share code whilst having their own data.

Comment: @user1257931 Hi, I update my question, the problem is that I can not find __dso_handle_ptr ..

Comment: What do you see if you run the ELF binary through

  objdump -t {bin} | grep -i handle

Comment: @user1257931 It will generate this line:  **0804e0ac l  O .data 00000000              __dso_handle**

Comment: @user1257931 all right, so basically I think this should be a version checking routine... probably I should just remove it cause it will not harm the functionality unless I can find some better way

Comment: It looks like IDA Pro is referencing that data segment is loaded with the address located as __dso_handle which is a pointer (hence the _ptr suffix).  You may want to get further clarification on the IDA Pro forums https://www.hex-rays.com/forum/ucp.php?mode=login

Comment: @computereasy could you just press enter on its name? :'(  I think you gonna see smth like `__dso_handle_ptr dd offset __dso_handle`